# Is there a way to retrieve text file values on the other machine in Eggplant?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, eggplant

I'm having a hard time reading text file from the other machine. I already tried to mapped the file like this **\10.212.9.20\Eggplant\Test\propertyfile.txt**. But it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
set the itemDelimiter to "="
    repeat with theParams = each line of file "\\10.212.9.20\Eggplant\Test\propertyfile.txt"
    insert item 2 of theParams after myList
end repeat

put item 6 of myList into ServerURL
put item 10 of myList into Username
put item 9 of myList into Password
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to open a file on the system you are testing you can have eggPlant open the file in a text editor and use ctrl+a ctrl+c to copy it's text into the clipboard. You can then parse this text similarly to if it were a file.

```
-- Assuming you have located the file and opened it in a text editor.
click(SomeLocationWithinTheTextEditor)
typeText ControlKey, "a" -- select all
typeText ControlKey, "c" -- copy to clipboard

set myTextFile = remoteClipboard(5) -- Wait up to 5 seconds to return the clipboard content

set the item delimiter to "="
repeat for each line of myTextFile
    insert item 2 of it after myList
end repeat

put item 6 of myList into ServerURL
put item 9 of myList into Password
put item 10 of myList into Username
```

Answer (score 0):

> "\10.212.9.20\Eggplant\Test\propertyfile.txt"

Are you running eggPlant on Windows? eggPlant Functional on Windows can only resolve letter-mapped drives, so if you map the shared drive to your eggPlant machine with a letter (i.e. D:\, E:) then you will be able to interact with the file saved on the other machine:

repeat with theParams = each line of file "D:\Eggplant\Test\propertyfile.txt"

Comment: Thanks! But I have a delimiter "=" in between of keys and values. For e.g. username=bob

Comment: I need to pass parameters values on my eggplant variables based on their respective keys.